# How to get the pagelayouts from sharepoint using graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get pagelayouts from sharepoint site using graph api but getting error.

Am able to see master page gallery through website

Can any one help me am stuck with this

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/sites/{sub-site-id}/drive/root:/_catalogs/masterpage/PageLayouts:/children

{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "The resource could not be found.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-03-14T18:01:31",
            "request-id": "a05bc326-02e9-4fad-ad92-cfb62144161d",
            "client-request-id": "4958fc74-4d2e-7bc0-6fbc-a7f1a0cccad3"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Graph API beta which has endpoint for [site pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sitepage?view=graph-rest-beta)

```
GET /beta/sites/{site-id}/sites/{sub-site-id}/pages
```

Page has property [pageLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sitepage?view=graph-rest-beta#properties).

You can inspect more details like [webParts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webpart?view=graph-rest-beta)

```
GET /beta/sites/{sitesId}/sites/{sub-site-id}/pages/{sitePageId}/webparts
```